# New Dell Computer Windows 10 (XPS) gives strange multi-window monitor

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps

How do I turn off the multi-window monitor that comes on my dell XPS 15 computer.  Attached is a picture of what I'm seeing

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vk67ge47jhkn78m/scr1.png?dl=0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Dell display manager - which gives you options other than the traditional aerosnap layouts.

The icon looks somewhat like this:

[image]

as per the [manual](https://www.quietpc.com/instructions/dell/dell-u2913wm_User%27s%20Guide2_en-us.pdf). I believe that shutting down the application or simply uninstalling it will make your multi window option go away.

Comment: I strongly suggest removing any third-part software that comes with any Dell.  There isn't a single peice of software offered by Dell that is required for your system to function.  Additionally, Dell like other OEMs often sneak in "security software" that break SSL/TLS connections due to how they function.  I don't trust any OEM software, farther then I can throw that kid from TLC, and I can't throw that kid very far.

Comment: eh. That's snake oil here. I consider it *redundant* unless you wanted to do vertical split screen, sure but *this* is just rebranded stuff from entech, and actually does what you want it to do very well *as long as you only run dell displays*. Otherwise it refuses to run. Its perfectly innocent, and actually sometimes useful.

Comment: The monitor software might be useful in specific cases.  I have specific examples of non-snake oil problems with OEM software though

Comment: The program is now "Dell Premiere Color".  Who would have guessed that is a windows manager.

Comment: ._. Pretty sure that was only 2 years ago. Its probably the same badge engineered software from entech ;p

Comment: An Office Space joke! Just don't take my red stapler!  Believe you mean Initech though :-)

Comment: [Entech] (http://entechtaiwan.com/) Used to have a *legendary* tool called powerstrip and a ton of useful low level monitor control APIs